# How to solve Duplicated key in hash literal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rubocop

I have an action like

```
@documents = Document.all.includes(:user, user: :skills, user: :profession)
```

When I run rubocop on my controller, I get this result:

```
controllers/documents_controller.rb:4:75: W: Lint/DuplicatedKey: Duplicated key in hash literal.
    @documents = Document.all.includes(:user, user: :skills, user: :profession)
                                                             ^^^^
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
Document.all.includes(:user, { user: [:skills, :profession] })
```

[`Eager Loading Multiple Associations`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: You don't need the explicit curly braces for the hash.